# If I read a JSON array from a file, then I get out the old unchanged array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I'm reading about `require`ing a JSON object from a file. I can read the JSON correctly, but after I add data to it and save it into the file, re-requiring doesn't get the updated JSON, but retrieves the old file. Can someone explain why this is so? How can I fix this?

```
var file = process.env[(process.platform == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'] + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\BetterDiscord\\plugins\\Test.json";
var json = require(file);
console.log(JSON.stringify(json.img));
json.img.push({name:"Test"});
console.log(JSON.stringify(json.img));
save(JSON.stringify(json), file);
json = require(file);
console.log(JSON.stringify(json.img));
```

This is the `save` method:

```
var save = function(value, file){
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile(file, value, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};
```

This is the Output:

```
Output 1: [{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"}]
Output 2: [{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"}, {"name":"Test"}]
Output 3: [{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"}]
```

Comment: Probably because of module caching. Why not just re-read the file using `fs.readFile`? Why use `require` here?

Comment: `require` will cache results to avoid reloading the same files multiple times

Comment: Do you **close** the file???

Comment: after the save function is called did you check your file? is {"name":"Test"} is added to the file or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` will [cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) the file. Instead of requiring, use the [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) method to read the file again.

```
json = fs.readFileSync(file);
```

Also, as @MikeC points out, you're writing to the file asynchronously, so either switch that out for the synchronous version `writeFileSync`, or rewrite your code using with `readFile` and `writeFile` and use callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

There's two major problems with your code. The first is that `save` is an asynchronous function. That means that any code you write directly after it will run before it completes. It works just like `setTimeout` in that regard.

```js
console.log(1);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(2);
}, 100);
console.log(3);
```

Notice how it outputs `3` before `2`. That's because `setTimeout`, like `fs.writeFile`, is asynchronous. To make sure you run code *after* it's done, you can pass a callback or use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (outside of the scope of this question but very useful). So your code could look something like this.

```js
const save = (path, cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb();
  }, 100);
};

let path = 'path/to/file';
save(path, () => {
  console.log(`Saved ${path}`);
});
console.log(`Saving ${path}...`);
```

This whole thing could also be avoided by using the `sync` version of `writeFile`.

```
fs.writeFileSync(file, value);
```

The next problem stems from how `require` caches the results. It does this because it's intended for loading in modules and they will not be changing dynamically, most of the time. Instead, load the file from the system directly. This can also be used asynchronously or synchronously. Here's how I would rewrite your code using synchronous code (although asynchronous is generally preferable).

```
var fs = require('fs');
var save = function(value, file){
    return fs.writeFileSync(file, value);
};

var file = process.env[(process.platform == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'] + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\BetterDiscord\\plugins\\Test.json";
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8'));
obj.img.push({name:"Test"});
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.img));
save(JSON.stringify(obj), file);
obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8'));
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.img));
```